# How to apply INotifyPropertyChanged to Material Design Snackbar in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

The Framework [Material Design Snackbar] [1](https://material.io/components/snackbars)

```xml
    <materialDesign:Snackbar x:Name="MainSnackbar" 
        MessageQueue="{materialDesign:MessageQueue}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

I want to setup one materialDesign:Snackbar in the MainWindow and accessed by all the UserControls of my WPF app.

But when the one button of the selected user control enqueued the msg, another button of the selected user control can't enqueue msg and triggered an exception.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: What exception did it throw?

Comment: Only allow one process access this variable, event this MessageQueue declare as static.